# Duplicate rows in the View table

Tags: database, view, relation

I created a **view**. The output information is **duplicate**. Where's the problem?
See the image in the link below
Help me please

[Duplicate rows in the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5H5o.jpg)

Comment: Hi, please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The rows are not duplicated, they have unique Check Number, if you want the output has unique CodePeigirySerfaresh for example, you can group by that column or use distinct keyword and remove select column Check Number.